# converting a can message object to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, can-bus

1. My Log is stored into a list in the following format:

log = [can.Message(timestamp=1551734911.0096931, arbitration_id=0x14ff0065, extended_id=True, channel=2, dlc=8, data=[0xf4, 0x7c, 0x89, 0x35, 0x28, 0xf, 0xea, 0xe]), can.Message(timestamp=1551734911.0102572, arbitration_id=0x14ff0165, extended_id=True, channel=2, dlc=8, data=[0x40, 0x14, 0x0, 0x36, 0xd0, 0x39, 0x60, 0x22]), can.Message(timestamp=1551734911.0108252, arbitration_id=0x14ff0265, extended_id=True, channel=2, dlc=8, data=[0x80, 0x35, 0x9, 0xf, 0x8c, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0]), can.Message(timestamp=1551734911.0114133, arbitration_id=0x14fef100, extended_id=True, channel=2, dlc=8, data=[0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff])]

Goal: To convert the log into a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
timestamp   arbitration_id  extended_id channel dlc data
```

0   1551734911.00969    0x14ff0065  TRUE    2   8   [0xf4, 0x7c, 0x89, 0x35, 0x28, 0xf, 0xea, 0xe]
1   1551734911.01025    =0x14ff0165 TRUE    2   8   [0x40, 0x14, 0x0, 0x36, 0xd0, 0x39, 0x60, 0x22]
2   1551734911.01082    0x14ff0265  TRUE    2   8   [0x80, 0x35, 0x9, 0xf, 0x8c, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0]

I tried the following code:

```
log = can.BLFReader(filename)
log = list(log)
df = pd.DataFrame(log)
print(df.head(5))
```

Output:

```
                                               0
```

0  Timestamp: 1551734911.009693    ID: 14ff0065  ...
1  Timestamp: 1551734911.010257    ID: 14ff0165  ...
2  Timestamp: 1551734911.010825    ID: 14ff0265  ...
3  Timestamp: 1551734911.011413    ID: 14fef100  ...
4  Timestamp: 1551734911.011973    ID: 14ff0068  ...

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import can

print(pd.__version__)

log = [can.Message(timestamp=1551734911.0096931, arbitration_id=0x14ff0065, extended_id=True, channel=2, dlc=8, data=[0xf4, 0x7c, 0x89, 0x35, 0x28, 0xf, 0xea, 0xe]), can.Message(timestamp=1551734911.0102572, arbitration_id=0x14ff0165, extended_id=True, channel=2, dlc=8, data=[0x40, 0x14, 0x0, 0x36, 0xd0, 0x39, 0x60, 0x22]), can.Message(timestamp=1551734911.0108252, arbitration_id=0x14ff0265, extended_id=True, channel=2, dlc=8, data=[0x80, 0x35, 0x9, 0xf, 0x8c, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0]), can.Message(timestamp=1551734911.0114133, arbitration_id=0x14fef100, extended_id=True, channel=2, dlc=8, data=[0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff])]

df_data = [{'timestamp':m.timestamp, 'arbitration_id':m.arbitration_id, 'extended_id':m.is_extended_id, 'channel':m.channel, 'dlc': m.dlc, 'data':m.data} for m in log]
df = pd.DataFrame(df_data)
```